# How to get FCM token?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-chrome, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to get FCM token in react js application.
First thing i tried is to use `messaging.useServiceWorker(registration)` then use `messaging.getToken()` and it's working fine on localhost for firefox and google chrome, but on an HTTPS live server it works fine on firefox but in chrome it throws an error:  `DOMException: Failed to execute 'subscribe' on 'PushManager': Subscription failed - no active Service Worker`.

I saw firebase docs and found that [`messaging.useServiceWorker`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.messaging.Messaging#useserviceworker) is deprecated now and I have to use [`messaging.getToken({ serviceWorkerRegistration })`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.messaging.Messaging#gettoken) instead but it throws an error:  `FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:3000/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope') with script ('http://localhost:3000/firebase-messaging-sw.js'): The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html'). (messaging/failed-service-worker-registration).`

**Notes**

- *firebase-messaging-sw.js* File is under the public directory.
- *firebase-messaging-sw.js* File is empty.
- This how I register the service worker:

```js
export const registerServiceWorker = () => {
  if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      navigator.serviceWorker
      .register(process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/firebase-messaging-sw.js")
      .then(function (registration) {
        console.log("[registration]", registration)
        
        // messaging.useServiceWorker(registration)



          resolve(registration);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
          console.log("[ERROR registration]: ", err)
          reject(null);
        });
    });
  } else {
    console.log("SERVICE WORKER NOT IN THE BROWSER")
  }
};
```

What should I do to get FCM token in a write way?

Comment: Did you get this to work?

Comment: @Leo I stopped working on it, and I will continue on it maybe tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution for this issue here is my code:

```
class Firebase {
  constructor() {
    if (firebase.apps.length) return;
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
    this.auth = firebase.auth();
    this.messaging = firebase.messaging();
    navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations().then((registrations) => {
      if (registrations.length) {
         [this.registration] = registrations;
         return;
      }
      navigator.serviceWorker
        .register("/firebase-message-sw.js")
        .then((registration) => {
           this.registration = registration;
        });
      });
  }

  async askNotificationPermission() {
    try {
      const token = await this.messaging.getToken({
        serviceWorkerRegistration: this.registration,
      });
      return token;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("[FIREBASE ERROR]: ", error);
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

And I am firing *askNotificationPermission* function with a click action.